# Highcharts - Change Measurement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/zf3m6/4/

I can not figure out how to change the measurement from 'mm' to 'km'.

Here is the current code:

```
$(function () {

    var tmpSerie = [{
        name: '20 and over',
        color: 'Red',
        data: [192]

    }, {
        name: 'Under 20',
        color: 'Green',
        data: [0, 173]

    }, {
        name: 'Zero',
        color: 'Blue',
        data: [0, 0, 25.1]

    }, {
        name: 'Not Assessed',
        color: 'Black',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 1.5]

    }],
        series = [],
        len = tmpSerie.length,
        i,j,data,dataLen;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        data = [];
        dataLen = tmpSerie[i].data.length;

        for(j=0;j<dataLen;j++) {
            console.log(tmpSerie[i].data[j]);
            if(tmpSerie[i].data[j] > 0) {
                data.push(tmpSerie[i].data[j]);
            }
        }

        series.push({
            name: tmpSerie[i].name,
            color: tmpSerie[i].color,
            data: data
        });
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '20 and over',
                'Under 20',
                'Zero',
                'Not Assessed']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,




title: {
                text: 'Kilometers'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: series
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want to change the measurement on the tooltip just change mm for km on the pointFormat like this [http://jsfiddle.net/zf3m6/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/zf3m6/5/)

Comment: do you mean that you just want it so say 'km' instead of 'mm'? Or that you need to change the data to reflect km instead of mm?  If just the formatting, change the pointFormat text...  if the data, just divide each point by 1000...